# Copy-Item / Remove-Item child-content only without root folder?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Hi I'm struggling mightily with the following - suppose I have the following directory structure C:\Temp\Test1 and C:\Temp\Test2

What I'd like to do is recursively copy the child-contents of C:\Temp\Test1 to C:\Temp\Test2 without copying the actual folder C:\Temp\Test1 ..right now if I use the command

```
Copy-Item C:\Temp\Test1 C:\Temp\Test2 -Recurse
```

Will result in C:\Temp\Test2\Test1 and no combination of parameters seems to alleviate the problem

Similarly, when I wish to remove all the child content in C:\Temp\Test2 I wish to only delete the child content and not the actual folder eg

```
Remove-Item C:\Temp\Test2\ -Recurse
```

Is removing the \Test2 folder. I've tried so many variations of parameters - how can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [get-childitem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx) command. You can use this in the pipeline to copy or remove all items underneath the root folders:

```
# recursively copy everything under C:\Temp\Test1 to C:\Temp\Test2
get-childitem "C:\Temp\Test1" | % { 
    copy-item $_.FullName -destination "C:\Temp\Test2\$_" -recurse 
}

# recursively remove everything under C:\Temp\Test1
get-childitem "C:\Temp\Test1" -recurse | % { 
    remove-item $_.FullName -recurse 
}
```

Comment: Note that you do not need to wrap the cmdlet calls in a foreach (`... | % { cmdlet $_.FullName ... }`); both [`Copy-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113292) and [`Remove-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373) will automatically accept input from the pipeline. E.g. the second example can be simplified to `Get-ChildItem "$env:temp\Test1" | Remove-Item -Recurse`.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Copy-Item C:\Temp\Test1\* C:\Temp\Test2
    Remove-Item "C:\Temp\Test2\*" -recurse
```

Works too :)

Comment: copy-item does preserve (even with recurse or container) a folder structure in Test1....

Comment: @FalcoAlexander is right, don't upvote this post it is not right

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1152895/powershell-copy-item-recursively-but-dont-include-folder-name / https://superuser.com/questions/1152895/powershell-copy-item-recursively-but-dont-include-folder-name

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @edelwater's comment, there is simple and correct answer over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1152895/powershell-copy-item-recursively-but-dont-include-folder-name), which I'll reproduce here:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\FolderA\*" -Destination "C:\FolderB\" -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

The key is to add the `*` at the end of the source path.

Assuming `FolderA` and `FolderB` are both folders in your current directory and  `FolderA` contains the following:

```
|-- File1.txt
|-- Subdirectory1
|   |-- File2.txt
|   |-- File3.txt
|-- Subdirectory2
    |-- File4.txt
```

Then the following:

```
$MySource = "FolderA"
$MyDest = "FolderB"

Copy-Item `
  -Path (Join-Path $MySource "*") `
  -Destination $MyDest `
  -Recurse `
  -Force
```

Creates this structure within `FolderB`

```
|-- File1.txt
|-- Subdirectory1
|   |-- File2.txt
|   |-- File3.txt
|-- Subdirectory2
    |-- File4.txt
```

Without the `*` in the source folder path, you'll end up with:

```
|-- FolderA
    |-- File1.txt
    |-- Subdirectory1
    |   |-- File2.txt
    |   |-- File3.txt
    |-- Subdirectory2
        |-- File4.txt
```